# how to organize an unusual connection OneToOne Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine

There is Entity in which you need to implement the `OneToOne` relationship, but the problem is that the connection between them is carried out by fields that are not key and there are several of them.

```
    class MyEntityOne
    {
        
        protected $ id;
        protected $ pole1;
        protected $ pole2;
        protected $ pole3;
        protected $ myEntytyTwo;
         
    }
    
    class MyEntityTwo
    {
        protected $ pole1;
        protected $ pole2;
        protected $ pole3;
        protected $ pole4;
        protected $ pole5;
        protected $ myEntytyOne;
    }
```

The relationship between them is:

`SELECT * FROM MyEntityOne O LEFT JOIN MyEntityTwo T ON (o.pole1 = t.pole1 and o.pole2 = t.pole2 and o.pole2 = t.pole2 and t.pole5 = 1)`

I did not find in the documentation how to better implement this connection, I will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Is the thing you are trying to archieve to fetch entities from table where the pole1, pole2 and pole3 are the same? Or are they actually mapped with @OneToOne?

Comment: @B0re I need to get pole4 if pole1, pole2, pole3 meet and pole5 = 1

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
        /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('o')
            ->from('App\Entity\MyEntityOne', 'o')
            ->join('App\Entity\MyEntityTwo', 't')
            ->where(
                'o.pole1 = t.pole1',
                'o.pole2 = t.pole2',
                'o.pole3 = t.pole3',
                't.pole5 = 1'
            )
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need, but I have a question how to describe it in `Entity`